# Type safety in for in loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

I've been experimenting with type safety in objective c for a while now. I think I got some of it, but I am wondering if the following is possible.

```
NSMutableArray <NSNumber *> *x = [NSMutableArray new];
[x addObject:@14];
[x addObject:@"s"]; // <--- Gives warning, good!

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < x.count; i++) {
    NSString *s = [x objectAtIndex:i]; // <-- Gives warning, good!
}

NSString *d = x[0]; // <-- Gives warning, good!


//but
for (NSString *s in x) // <-- expected warning but didn't get it
    NSLog(@"%@", [s stringByAppendingString:@"s"]; // <-- no warning just run time error
```

So my question is can a for in loop give a warning when an incorrect object is used. I want to use the for in since it is fast and hides details of implementation.

Comment: Obj-C doesn't implement generics. Not really. The generics it has are there for Swift support. It doesn't mean they will be enforced in Obj-C code. Maybe in the future but unfortunately it would involve compatibility problems so I don't think it's probable.

Comment: If the person who gave minus could explain it that would be great! I really want to grok this subject. So if i am unclear or just plain stupid just tell me

Comment: Probably just an oversight in the compiler.

Comment: @KenThomases Not sure this is just an oversight. The way to for in loop works is through NSFastEnumeration protocol and the method returns a NSInteger (correct me if i am wrong). It could be it is just not possible to get the compiler warning because of the way for in works.

Comment: Did you post this on the dev forum?

Comment: @sbarow No, but will do now

Comment: It doesn't matter how it's implemented. The compiler has to recognize it and can analyze it at the syntactical and semantic level. In other words, it's trivial for us to recognize and even to conceive how to implement the check in the compiler. It's certainly possible and would be appropriate, so an oversight.

Comment: @KenThomases Makes sense. I've asked this question on dev forum aswel. Will keep this one alive until I can definitely  tell why this happens

Answer (score 2):

Here's the issue.

Most of the `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` methods such as `addObject:` and `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` (which allows for the modern `[index]` syntax) take or return `ObjectType` values. `ObjectType` is a special indicator that means "use the generic type" specified for the array.

The fast enumeration comes from the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol and its `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` method. Unfortunately, the `objects` parameter is a C-array of `id`. It doesn't use `ObjectType`. Since the objects are type `id`, the compiler can't do any type checking like it can for the other methods of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug. implementation details like NSFastEnumeration don't matter. they should at least check it in an analyzer pass if they don't manage to emit a warning. please file bug reports at Apple and LLVM